# ERROR 13 (HY000) at line 1: Can't get stat of (Errcode: 13)

Tags: mysql

Via SSH client I tried to connect with mysql and add a new database:

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -e "create database psa"
```

and I get this message:

```
ERROR 13 (HY000) at line 1: Can't get stat of './psa' (Errcode: 13)
```

I tried this too:
1-`mysql -uadmin -p'cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow'`
and I am connected to mysql server but once I type:

```
mysql> create database psa;
```

I receive this message:

```
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './psa' (Errcode: 13)
```

How to add a database to mysql server?

Comment: Not fully sure but I'd dare say it's an OS permission error. Can your user read from `/etc/psa`?

Comment: But why create database psa; fails cause the first commad mysql -uadmin -p'cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow' works fine so this not a permission issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The mysql (Errcode: 13) :

```
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './database-name'
```

means that mysqlserver have no permissions to access this database.
How to fix it via ssh client?

1-Go to your mysql directory:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/
```

2-Give the default permission to the required database so MYSQL server can access it:

```
chown mysql:mysql database-name/ -R
```

and done.
but what if once I type `SHOW databases;`and get `ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13)` that means MYSQL server have no permission to acces the whole mysql directory:

```
cd /var/lib/
```

then `chown mysql:mysql mysql/ -R`

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for the "Error 13 Can't Stat " is that the target file is not within the /var/lib/mysql directory hierarchy.  Apparently the mysql server approaches the file system quite differently than a normal user.

I was trying to load/update a table with:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/pi/sites.csv'
```

and MySQL (MariaDB actually) would barf with Error 13 no matter what I did to permissions.  Annoyingly, it would give this Permission Denied error even if the the file didn't exist, which was sufficient clue for me to remember that on a Win10 installation, the sites.csv source was in an Upload folder in the MySql hierarchy.

Once I moved sites.csv into /var/lib/mysql/ens2_0 and referenced it without an absolute path, it worked a charm.